# Can I host a game server behind a VPN?

Tags: hosting

I'm considering getting a VPN for my PC to keep my data encrypted. I have tried doing this before but had no choice but the switch back because people could not connect to my game servers (Such as Minecraft, Gmod, etc.). I made these servers through port forwarding and whatnot. My question is if there is a workaround to this problem or if there is an alternative to the traditional VPN to allow people to join?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a VPN then there's really only 2 options to get people to connect to your game servers:

1. Your game server traffic goes through the VPN and anyone who wishes to join must be connected to your VPN to be able to do so. In other words you need to give access to your VPN to anyone you want to get into your server. This is a bad idea for public servers.
2. You configure your VPN in a way that your game server traffic does not go through it and anyone who knows your server address will be able to join (provided that the server is configured correctly).

More on [VPNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by your question and what you are trying to achieve. A VPN routes all your network traffic as if you were in another network. Most network functions under a basic setup will use one set of rules for traffic direction, and that would be "all traffic goes through the VPN when leaving my computer when I am connected to the VPN" which would be the exact reason as to why your hosted servers are failing. What data are you encrypting? Most home users and gamers don't need this kind of security. My best guess is you might be Canadian and using a VPN to get US Netflix, but I digress.

Since there are no specifics on what your set up is, I will answer the question asked.

What you're asking to do is not technically impossible, but requires a large amount of customization and network traffic redirection. For example you would have to put rules in place that state "Minecraft traffic ignores VPN" and "Other Internet browsing uses VPN". Depending on your operating system you may even need additional software to accomplish this kind of traffic management.

Answer (score 0):

Considered that you host your own VPN, it is possible.

I'll not detail the process but be sure to check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55791/port-forward-to-vpn-client